# How to test and debug changes to a local AOSP build using the emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-service, android-source, android-build

I am interested in building AOSP locally and running it inside of an emulator locally. Is this possible? If so, how can one test and debug the changes locally while running the emulator? Where can one find the emulator in the build and how can one start the emulator via CLI or in Android Studio?

Would it be possible to test and debug steps starting from the App across Android App (Kotlin/Java), Android Framework (Java) and Android HAL (Native)?

Answer (score 3):

Android AOSP supports running emulators in the form of AVD (Android Virtual Device), give it a read here:

https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/avd

You need to sync AOSP as usual and then select the correct product in the lunch menu, for example, `sdk_phone_x86_64` . When you run make, at the end of the successful build you just need to pass the command `$ emulator` and the image should bootup. Please go through the link shared.

Debugging should be available via ADB.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Are all changes made in AOSP Framework (Java, C++), HAL and Kernel reflected in the Emulator? In other words, is recommended to test/debug your app on top of the emulator? Are there any tradeoffs between test/debugging on the emulator vs. a physical device?

Comment: 1) yes, correct. 2) you can test/debug on emulator unless your code depends on hardware features missing /  not properly simulated in AVD.

Comment: IMHO, the emulator is the best way to test your code, unless like Mixaz, mentioned above, if you have a hardware dependency. It all depends on your requirements. You can be more detailed and make the questions specific, then only people will be able to help you better :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems most of the changes (e.g. Java source) to the `aosp/framework/*` source code will be reflected in the emulator.  If I were to make changes to any native source inside the `aosp/hardware/*` directory, would they be reflected in the emulator? Or would only a specific directory in `hardware` correspond to the emulator?